# не понимаю как работает querySelector

Tags: javascript, html

хочу чтобы querySelector выделял все radio но он выбирает только первый

```js
let checkbox = document.querySelectorAll('.form__checkbox');

checkbox.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    document.getElementById('33').disabled = false;
})
```

```html
<ul class="form__menu">
                    <li class="form__item" id="crapItem">
                        <input class="form__checkbox" type="radio" name="presentationTopic" id="crapRadio"><label for="crapRadio">Rap / Pop</label>
                    </li>
                    <li class="form__item">
                        <input class="form__checkbox" type="radio" name="presentationTopic" id="blackRadio"><label for="blackRadio">Black Metal</label>
                    </li>
                    <li class="form__item">
                        <input class="form__checkbox" type="radio" name="presentationTopic" id="thrashRadio"><label for="thrashRadio">Thrash Metal</label>
                    </li>
                    <li class="form__item">
                        <input class="form__checkbox" type="radio" name="presentationTopic" id="punkRadio"><label for="punkRadio">Punk</label>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <button class="form__confirm btn" onclick="confirmMusicGenre()" id="33" disabled>Confirm!</button>
```

Comment: querySelectorAll()

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: checkbox.addEventListener is not a function
    at , если просто добавить querySelectorAll

Comment: querySelectorAll возвращает коллекцию из нескольких элементов, по которой нужно пройтись каким-нибудь циклом

Comment: Так это же азбука! мне было бы стыдно такие вопросы задавать, даже когда был совсем зеленым, я сначала всегда гуглил...

Comment: спасибо, за словесную поддержку в моих начинаниях

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.querySelectorAll` возвращает ноду - массив элементов.

Вот так можно повесить `eventListener` на каждый элемент ноды:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('a').forEach(elem => {
  elem.addEventListener('click', ev => {
    console.log(ev.target.className)
  });
});
```

```html
<a href="#" class="link-1">Нажми</a>
<a href="#" class="link-2">Нажми</a>
```

Вот пример конкретно для вашего случая:

```js
let checkbox = document.querySelectorAll('.form__checkbox');

checkbox.forEach(elem => {
  elem.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    document.getElementById('33').disabled = false;
  });
});
```

```html
<ul class="form__menu">
  <li class="form__item" id="crapItem">
    <input class="form__checkbox" type="radio" name="presentationTopic" id="crapRadio"><label for="crapRadio">Rap / Pop</label>
  </li>
  <li class="form__item">
    <input class="form__checkbox" type="radio" name="presentationTopic" id="blackRadio"><label for="blackRadio">Black Metal</label>
  </li>
  <li class="form__item">
    <input class="form__checkbox" type="radio" name="presentationTopic" id="thrashRadio"><label for="thrashRadio">Thrash Metal</label>
  </li>
  <li class="form__item">
    <input class="form__checkbox" type="radio" name="presentationTopic" id="punkRadio"><label for="punkRadio">Punk</label>
  </li>
</ul>
<button class="form__confirm btn" onclick="confirmMusicGenre()" id="33" disabled>Confirm!</button>
```

Comment: большое спасибо, как раз читал за forEach но ставил не там где надо